# Can't download tf nightly 2.0 preview

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to download the tf nightly preview but keep getting the following error:
[image]

I read that it should download if you have the 3.6.x version of Python so I downgraded to that and it still doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/console output. Please copy-paste the terminal content into your question

Answer (score 0):

That library does simply not exist (anymore). Tensorflow 2.0 was released in September 2019, so they probably didn't keep the nightly preview of it around. If you want the *current* nightly, then you should do

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

If you want tensorflow 2.0, then do

```
pip install tensorflow=2.0
```